# Idiom for a situation with no reliance and trust

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom or expression for a situation or a part of time that there's an atmosphere of distrust and  every one is cheating each other and no one can be able to find a trusthworthy person?

Comment: if it's about a  time or place you could say"there's an atmosphere of distrust" . It's a quite common expression.

Answer (score 5):

I think such a world can be described as a **dog-eat-dog** world. — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dog+eat+dog)

This might also be considered as a world where **anything goes**. — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/anything+goes)

> if a situation is dog eat dog, people will do anything to be successful, even if what they do harms other people.
>
> *"In showbusiness it's dog eat dog - one day you're a star, the next you've been replaced by younger talent."*

Comment: Lenz, I've expanded your answer for you. We do not want one-liner answers here.

Answer (score 4):

The expression "**There is no honor among thieves**" can sometimes be used in a figurative sense, where "thieves" is understood to mean any disreputable people.

Answer (score 3):

**Every man for himself** (and the devil take the hindmost) — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+man+for+himself)

> *Prov.* Everyone has to fight for his or her own survival. (You can use this to describe an extremely competitive situation.)
>
> *"At first we tried to help each other study for the exam, but soon it was every man for himself, and the devil take the hindmost."*
> *"The inventors tried to collaborate, agreeing to share the profits from their invention, but they grew so suspicious of each other that each began to work separately, and devil take the hindmost."*
> *"When the ship began to sink, it was every man for himself."*